# Get me the other items also bought with particular product, in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following two tables:

- Order: Id, other info
- Product: Id, Name, other info
- OrderProduct: OrderId, ProductId, other info

We are all aware that two orders can contain multiple products, and between those two orders, they can have one or more products in common.

What is the LINQ for pulling the other distinct products bought with a particular product? There is an answer that is plain SQL, but I need the LINQ equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
var matchingOrders = from op in OrderProduct
                     where op.ProductId == desiredProductId
                     select OrderId;
var otherProductsOnSameOrder = (from op in OrderProduct
                                where matchingOrders.Contains(op.OrderId) && op.ProductId != desiredProductId
                                select op.ProductId).Distinct();
```